# Let $V=\mathbb{R}[X]_{3}$ and basis $B=\{1+X,X+X^2,X^2+X^3,X^3\}$. What is the image of $P_{1}(X)=2+6X+3X^2+4X^3$ under $T:V \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Initially, I thought that I had to differentiate the basis B but I'm not sure. If this is not the case, I have no idea what to do. I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: You simply need to write $P_1$ as a linear combination of the basis elements. The resulting vector in $\Bbb R^4$ will consist of the coefficients.

Comment: What I have done now is $2(1+X)+4(X+X^2)+(-1)(X^2+X^3)+5(X^3)$, which are the basis elements in order to get $P_{1}(X)$. Is this correct? And also what is the next step? Many Thanks!

Comment: That's correct. The next step is to put the coefficients in a column vector: $\pmatrix{2\\4\\-1\\5}$. That answers the question.

Comment: Thank you very much. When I was searching for the combination, I thought that the answer was including the zeros in the top an bottom corner, resulting in a 4x4 matrix. Now I notice that I was confused with something else. Appreciate it!